# Leetcode Question 21 Merge Two Sorted Lists

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Below is my proposed answer, it can not return the list with l1 and l2.

```
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        if (l1 == null) {
            return l2;
        }

        if (l2 == null) {
            return l1;
        }

        if (l1.val <= l2.val) {
            ListNode tmpNode_1 = l1;
            ListNode tmpNode_2 = l1.next;

            tmpNode_2 = mergeTwoLists(tmpNode_2, l2);

            //l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2);
            return tmpNode_1;
        } else {
            ListNode tmpNode_1 = l2;
            ListNode tmpNode_2 = l2.next;

            tmpNode_2 = mergeTwoLists(l1, tmpNode_2);

            // l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next);
            return tmpNode_1;
        }
    }
```

If I follow the commented code, then it works. What is the problem with the way I use variables?

Comment: Are you asking why some piece of code doesn't work when you comment out parts of it?

Comment: the commented part is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

I guess by defining those temp variables, you'd be disconnecting the two linked lists from the recursive algorithm, if you would use a debugger or print things out, you'd see.

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        if (l1 == null)
            return l2;
        if (l2 == null)
            return l1;
        if (l1.val < l2.val) {
            l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2);
            return l1;
        } else {
            l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next);
            return l2;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Solution {
    public static final ListNode mergeTwoLists(final ListNode l1, final ListNode l2) {
        if (l1 == null) {
            return l2;
        }

        if (l2 == null) {
            return l1;
        }

        final ListNode merged;

        if (l1.val < l2.val) {
            merged = l1;
            merged.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2);

        } else {
            merged = l2;
            merged.next = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next);
        }

        return merged;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Comment: Thank you so much. I get what you try to say.